# CodeIgniter view doesn't load

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an on-going CI v2.0.2 app that was coded by other developers.

I started off by creating a `trial` controller: `controllers/trial/trial.php'. The code in this controller is:

```
<h1>controller</h1>
<?php

class Trial extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        echo "this works";
        $this->load->view("trial/trial_view");
    }
}
```

And the view is in `views/trial/trial_view.php`. The view has a simple `<p>this is the view</p>` line.

Now when I visit the URL - `http://localhost/ci/index.php/trial/trial` all I get is the `<h1>` tag from the controller. If I remove that tag, nothing is seen, not even the `echo` statement.

The code base I was given is an exact replica of the app that is being used right now. I've doubly checked to make sure the folder structure is correct too.

What should be going on here? Any config options I should look at?

### Update--------

I moved `trial.php` into the `controllers` folder, and `trial_view.php` into the `views` folder. Made the appropriate changes in the code too. But the result is still the same - only the `h1` tag from the controller is displayed when I visit `http://localhost/ci/index.php/trial`

Answer (score 2):

your action is called `index`, while you're trying to access controller's `trial` action, which does not exist.

Comment: Well, the controller named `trial.php` is within a folder named `trial`. That's how I'm accessing the controller - `http://localhost/ci/index.php/sub-directory-within-controller/controller`. Is this incorrect?

Comment: check out [CI URI routing documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html), your url is using this pattern `index.php/controller/action/param`, in your case it should be `index.php/trial/index` or simply `index.php/trial`, since the `index` is a default action to be loaded when no action specified

Comment: I've updated the question - now the `trial.php` controller lies within the `controllers` folder. Likewise, I've moved the view and updated the code to reflect these changes. However, its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

change it to,

```
 function index() {
    echo "this works";
    $this->load->view("trial/trial_view");
}
```

try putting trial.php outside trial folder inside controller folder, and get back what happens

Comment: Sorry about that. The view is loaded as `$this->load->view("trial/trial_view");` I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: did u restrict anything with htaccess/routing config?

Comment: Well, `routes.php` says this much - `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome"; $route['404_override'] = '';` And the .htaccess in the `application` folder has `deny from all`.

Comment: try putting trial.php outside trial folder inside controller folder, and get back what happends

Comment: Yes.. I just tried that. And the result is the same - only the `h1` from the controller is shown. The url right now is `http://localhost/ci/index.php/trial/`

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
function index() {
        echo "this works";
        $this->load->view("trial/trial_view");
    }
```

to

```
public function index() {
        echo "this works";
        $this->load->view("trial/trial_view");
    }
```

BTW try turning on error reporting and see if error is thrown

**EDIT**

BTW i tested with your code with same setting. It is working in my machine

Comment: any function is public by default when no access specifier is given.

Comment: @rawry, I know just incase. Like, the code is working perfectly in my machine according to his settings, `controllers/trial/trial.php` and `views/trial/trial_view.php`

Comment: I set up a clean CI v2.1.2 project, and was able to access a controller from within a sub-directory, and the view too showed its output. So the issue must lie with the configuration of the initial project. Any pointers where I should look at?

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari, can you download version 2.0.2, make a clean install and try if that work?? There have been lots of changes from 2.0.2 to version 2.1.2. Download 2.0.2 Version http://downloads.codeigniter.com/reactor/CodeIgniter_2.0.2.zip

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari This way you can confirm if its problem in version 2.0.2 or in a configuration somewhere in your old app.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH: I just tried it out in v2.0.2, and the view loads properly. I tried it from within a subfolder too, and it worked. Seems like the problem is isolated to my initial project's config.

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari, try deleting htaccess (make a backup copy first), and see if htaccess is playing any role. Then compare routes.php with the fresh copy. I can just help you this much

Comment: @LoVeSmItH `routes.php` is the same in both the projects. Thanks for the help. I'll find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, stop using the index method to do anything. If your class is called Trial, you need to do this with the index method:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->trial();
}
```

Then do everything under a method called trial.